# Computer won't boot after memory upgrade

Tags: boot, memory, bios

I upgraded the memory on a computer, it's a roughly 4 year old PC, I switched the memory from a 4Gb to 8Gb and I think it won't boot though I'm not quite sure, it shows no image, not even the BIOS init screen.

#### Troubleshooting:

It has onboard graphics, both VGA and HDMI, unfortunately I don't have a VGA cable, is it possible that the default port was set to VGA and I can't see the image?

I switched back to the old ram and it still doesn't show any image.

I tried clearing the CMOS both by removing the battery and with the jumper, same result.

#### Hardware details:

The only info in the board is **BSWI-D2-N3050**, from what I could research it should take 8 Gb, it only has one memory slot.

Any ideas on what what I should try next?

Comment: 9 months old ? Then it was old stock, because this motherboard is a ECS board that is at least 5 years old. It should take a 8 GB RAM (SO-DIMM DDR3L, 1600 Mhz max.) Even with faster RAM it should still boot and let you get into Bios to adjust the RAM timing. Make sure the RAM has the L suffix. It will not like the version without L. Are there any beeps on attempted startup? If not I suspect the video. Either the cable or the monitor. Check if the monitor works on another computer. Make sure the monitor is looking at the correct input (if it has multiple).

Comment: If switching back to the old ram doesn't revive the system, then either the memory is not properly seated, or something got knocked loose, or something was damaged (ESD?) in the process.

Comment: @Tonny I never mention 9 months, I do mention 3/4 years old, the monitor works fine, I use it every day as a secondary screen on my laptop, the ram is not L but neither was the previous, It's regular DDR3 and it's been working fine till now, there are no beeps, but it beeps if I remove the memory, so the board seems to be working. I also suspect the video, but it worked before, so, it's ver confusing. The problem is that even if I put the old ram back, it doesn't work.

Comment: @user10489, it's seated correctly, if not, it beeps, I can't see how I wold damage anything, the old stick got out smoothly and the new one also, the computer's energy was off and I even drained the energy left, no carpet either, is it fixable if this was the case?

Comment: There's no certainty that there was damage, but if you were not properly grounded when handling the ram and touching the inside of the computer, damage is possible, and if the humidity was below 40%, likely.   See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_discharge

Comment: @anastaciu When you write 3/4 years most people will interpret that as "three-quarters" of a year or 9 months. Using "3 to 4 years" or "3-4 years" avoids that confusion. If you know the display is good I agree with user10489 that you accidentally knocked something loose or had an ESD problem. ESD is extremely unlikely since it still beeps when you take ALL memory out. So something seems loose.

Comment: @Tonny, oh, so that's what that is, changed it, anyway, I don't think I knocked anything out, but still, I'll check that, and I'll get a VGA cable, to rule that out.

Comment: I would suggest what @user10489 suggested. Does it BEEP when you turn it on? 3-Beeps means memory issue. Long + 8 BEEP means video issue.  More diagnose for that MB here: https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1023483/Ecs-Bswi-D2.html?page=59#manual

Comment: @RobertPaulsen great share, thanks, looking at it, the news are not the best, it appears that it may be a motheboard issue.

Comment: @anastaciu MB issue is a lot better than a video card issue. Mine is on the fritz and I'm looking around the house for stuff to sell to afford something that is 4 years old. :-0

Comment: @RobertPaulsen yes, those are expensive, if you want a decent one at least. Anyway I was able to make it work again, I left an answer with the details, in case anyone is wondering.

Comment: @Tonny, I was able to get it back with the old memory, details below, thanks again for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able to make it boot with the old memory, it took many attemps but I figured the roultine of removing the memory, clearing the CMOS with the jumper, turning it on without the memory, then inserting the memory, would make it boot after some attempts, I finally got a post indicating the the CMOS confings were wrong, after that is just a matter of loading the defaults (or setting it up yourself) and *voilá*.

Unfortunately this routine would not work with the larger 8GB memory stick so I had to give it back with the same memory, and only an SSD upgrade.

The strange thing is that the 4GB stick ends up working whereas the 8GB one doesn't, they both work at 1,35V.

I find no rationale as to why this is. Anyway, the owner hinted at the possibility of trying a DDR3L stick in a future iteration, but I'm a little traumatized by this board, so I'm not sure I want to see it again.

For anyone wondering here are the two sticks, notice that even the brand is the same, the only difference is really the capacity:

[image]

[image]

According to Tonny, in the comments below, it seems that, even though it's marked DDR3, it's really DDR3L, given the low 1,35V voltage.

Anyway, it would be best to spend a few more money and just to get rid of the board and get more up to date components.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working. I guess that the original 4GB RAM stick is really DDR3L even though it doesn't say so on the label. Or this 4GB stick is one of the rare ones that is technically DDR, but will "sort of" work when used in a DDR3L motherboard that has some margin in the power-feed to the RAM. This motherboard is designed for DDR3L ONLY and will not provide enough voltage for normal DDR. That is why the normal DDR3 8 GB stick didn't work.

Comment: I just checked the GoodRam website. That RAM is really DDR3L although they don't mentioned that. They only say it runs at 1.5V or 1.35V, but that just another way of saying that it is DDR3L. But the 8 GB stick should be the same. too! Looks like the motherboard for some reason just doesn't like this particular 8 GB stick. That's rare but not unknown. I would try another 8 GB DDR3L (by another brand if possible).

Comment: @Tonny, I only checked the specs, I wasn't aware that the L was just refering to the voltage, it's just one of those things, I even tried the memory in another board just to rule out the thin possibility of it being broke, but no, it worked fine.